# How to push UIViewController from AppDelgate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am building an iOS Application where there are 4 screen as - verify phone number,fb login, set your profile and home.
Now what I need is that if a user have set her profile info and after clicking on next if he close the app. On the restarting of the app it should directly get navigated to the home screen and there should not be repetition of all the 3 screens again.

What happens is, the screen 1  ( verify phone no ) is shown for a short period of time and then home screen appears. I want home screen to appear immediately after the splash screen when I reopen the app.

I am using below code.

> ```
> UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
>     UINavigationController *mvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
>     [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your initial view controller via your AppDelegate. Check your presentation clause and add target view controller as window rootviewcontroller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UINavigationController *navigationController;
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

if (YOUR_HOME_VIEW_PRESENTATION_LOGIC)
{
    navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
}
else
{
   // init with your phone view
    navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_PHONE_VIEW_IDENTIFIER"];
}

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

}
```

Also you could try to present your controller without animation - thais trick will remove unwanted animation

```
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mvc animated:NO completion:nil];
```